# How to retrieve LinqPad's connection list

Tags: linqpad

Is there a way to get connection objects list (servers AND databases) as objects so I can query them.

## Scenario

Let's say in my connection list there are

- 10 databases
- 5 servers

  - each server has at least 3 databases

I would like to be able to locate a table or stored procedure name  *ImReallyDifficultToLocate* in those connections

at the end I would like to be able to use something like this...

```
this.Mapping.GetTables()
    .Where(t=>t.TableName.Equals("[ImReallyDifficultToLocate]"))
    .Select (t => t.TableName).Dump();
```

Comment: Perhaps you would parse your ConnectionsV2.Xml file to determine the list of servers and databases and then manually create a SqlConnection and SqlCommand to issue something like select * from Sysobjects where name like '%ImReallyDifficultToLocate%'

Comment: @sgmoore please put this into an answer so I can mark it as answered ;-)  For those who don't know where the ConnectionsV2.Xml file is please check your %appdata%\LINQPad\ folder.  Also you may copy this file into your LinQPad folder and it will start to use that one instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you would parse your ConnectionsV2.Xml file (which should be located in your %appdata%\LINQPad\  folder) to determine the list of servers and databases and then manually create a SqlConnection and SqlCommand to issue something like

```
select * from Sysobjects where name like '%ImReallyDifficultToLocate%'
```